# Images upload successfully to aws s3 bucket but do not display on my site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, heroku, amazon-s3

I am using Rails with Heroku and AWS S3 to deploy a pinterest like website that I created through a tutorial. Users are successfully able to upload images to my s3 bucket. The problem is, uploaded images are supposed to display in the index (and show) but do not.

I created a bucket policy so the 'getobject' method is enabled.

```
{
"Id": "Policy1445210052484",
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "Stmt1445209989872",
        "Action": [
            "s3:GetObject"
        ],
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::wyattsbucket/*",
        "Principal": "*"
    }
]
```

}

Here is a screenshot of the postings on my site:

[image]
Heroku is not receiving any errors so I believe the problem is either in the S3 bucket or in my Rails environment. This is my first post, please forgive the amateur formatting, and if you have any ideas please let me know!

Thanks in advance.

= form_tag pins_path

views/pins/index.html.haml

```
#pins.transitions-enabled
  - @pins.each do |pin|
    .box.panel.panel-default
      = link_to (image_tag pin.image.url), pin
      .panel-body
        %h2= link_to pin.title, pin
        %p.user
        Submitted by
        = pin.user.email
```

models/pin.rb

```
class Pin < ActiveRecord::Base
    acts_as_votable
    belongs_to :user
    has_attached_file :image, styles: { medium: "500x500>" }
    validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/


end
```

Comment: please open a new question for the HTML!

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing your issue is with your policy. If you put the URL in your browser, can you view the image?

You could also try the below policy. I'm not that familiar with S3 policy's but this works for get's for me.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AddPerm",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::wyattsbucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: @wyattwade yeh, I can see it as well. The policy is working then. It must be something in your html. Can you post your HTML? check out this jsfiddle with working img tag. http://jsfiddle.net/cu033fm8/

Comment: I updated my S3 policy to match yours but still no luck.                                                                              I'm not sure if you are referring to the image URL or the heroku URL, but if you are referring to the image URL, it works! The image URL from the bucket shows the image.                                                                                                                                                                                      https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/wyattsbucket/pins/images/000/000/016/medium/as_surf_slater_2048.jpg

Comment: Yes i'll post my html.haml and my models. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @wyattwade great! please accept this answer if it was helpful and post a new html specific question so you can tag it properly and receive more answers